# How to loop through slides and not show empty slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have a slider, it loops fine through the slides until certain point when it displays an empty element

The issue is that at certain point in the loop, it will display the slider element with arrows without a slide, and then if you click on next or previous again it will continue displaying the slides

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlide(slideIndex);

function showSlide(index) {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var prev = document.querySelector(".prev");
  var next = document.querySelector(".next");

  if (index >= slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  } else if (index < 0) {
    slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
  } else {
    slideIndex = index;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex].style.display = "flex";
}

function plusSlide(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex + n);
}

var prev = document.querySelector(".prev");
prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
  plusSlide(-1);
});

var next = document.querySelector(".next");
next.addEventListener("click", function() {
  plusSlide(1);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-container {
  display: none
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 4rem;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px
}

.footer p {
  align-self: center
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px
}

.title {
  color: #6B7280;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.desc-slider {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.slider-project-btn {
  background-color: #100E1C;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px
}

span-slide {
  color: #FE744F;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-self: center;
}

.slide img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px
}

span .material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 900, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 78
}

.slide-text {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 60px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F0F0FB;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px
}

.slide-text h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.slide-text p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-right: 1px
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  selft-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .slide-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .slide-text p {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  .content {}
  .slide {
    overflow: hidden, display: none
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .slide-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .slide-text p {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  .slide {
    overflow: hidden
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://webtroniclabs.com/assets/img/carousel-img/carousel_BTC.webp" alt="Image 1">
      <div class="slide-text">
        <h3>BTC TRADE <br> PROJECT
        </h3>
        <p>A platform that brings sophisticated arbitrage features to crypto traders.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="desc">Web App</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Industry</p>
        <p class="desc">Trading</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Technology</p>
        <p class="desc">React
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="project-btn" onclick="window.location.href='https://webtroniclabs.com/portfolio/';">Full Project<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    trending_flat
    </span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://webtroniclabs.com/assets/img/carousel-img/carousel_Proflyt.webp" alt="Image 1">
      <div class="slide-text">
        <h3>PROLIFY <br> PROJECT
        </h3>
        <p class="desc-slider-final">ProFlyt is the first of its kind: the exclusive military aircrew scheduling platform designed for the US Air Force.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="desc">Web App</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Industry</p>
        <p class="desc">Trading</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Technology</p>
        <p class="desc">React
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="project-btn" onclick="window.location.href='https://webtroniclabs.com/portfolio/';">Full Project<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    trending_flat
    </span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://webtroniclabs.com/assets/img/carousel-img/carousel_Neutrality.webp" alt="Image 1">
      <div class="slide-text">
        <h3>NEUTRALITY <br> PROJECT
        </h3>
        <p>A Revolutionary News Aggregator and News Market Research Tool.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="desc">Web App</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Industry</p>
        <p class="desc">Communication</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Technology</p>
        <p class="desc">Angular / IA
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="project-btn" onclick="window.location.href='https://webtroniclabs.com/portfolio/';">Full Project<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    trending_flat
    </span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://webtroniclabs.com/assets/img/carousel-img/carousel_Neutrality.webp" alt="Image 1">
      <div class="slide-text">
        <h3>NEUTRALITY <br> PROJECT
        </h3>
        <p>A Revolutionary News Aggregator and News Market Research Tool.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="desc">Web App</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Industry</p>
        <p class="desc">Communication</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Technology</p>
        <p class="desc">Angular / IA
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="project-btn" onclick="window.location.href='https://webtroniclabs.com/portfolio/';">Full Project<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    trending_flat
    </span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://webtroniclabs.com/assets/img/carousel-img/carousel_Neutrality.webp" alt="Image 1">
      <div class="slide-text">
        <h3>NEUTRALITY <br> PROJECT
        </h3>
        <p>A Revolutionary News Aggregator and News Market Research Tool.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="desc">Web App</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Industry</p>
        <p class="desc">Communication</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <p class="title">Technology</p>
        <p class="desc">Angular / IA
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="project-btn" onclick="window.location.href='https://webtroniclabs.com/portfolio/';">Full Project<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    trending_flat
    </span></button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button class="prev">&#10094;</button>
<button class="next">&#10095;</button>
```

Comment: I would show a [mcve]. I created a test snippet with a generic array to just make sure it cycling through the array and it worked fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "empty element"? pls add html and css to reproduce the issue

Comment: It would display the slider element (main container) with arrows without a slide, and then if you click on next or previous again it will continue displaying the slides. Updated!

Comment: FWIW, I'm not seeing that problem. The only problem that I saw which turned out to not be a problem is you have 3 identical slides. So it Looked like it was malfunctioning but it was working. But I can't duplicate the empty slide issue. What process are you following to get that issue?